# Recuperar variável de dentro da função

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando recuperar uma variável de dentro da função no javascript

JavaScript

```js
function recVal(clickBuscaPje){

    clickBuscaPje = true;

    if (clickBuscaPje == true){
        console.log("Clicou no botão")
    }

    return clickBuscaPje;
}
```

HTML

```html
<button
  onclick="recVal(this)" 
  class="buscar_pje btn btn-warning"
  id="busca_pje"
  name="busca_pje"
>
  <i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i> Buscar no PJe
</button>
```

PHP:

```php
$btn = "<script> document.write(clickBuscaPje) </script>";

print $btn;

if ($btn == true) {
    print "<br>Clicou no botão<br>";
}
```

Preciso recuperar o valor dessa variável que existe dentro da função js em minha variável php.

algum de vcs já passou por isso e sabe resolver?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: `document.write(clickBuscaPje(true))`? de qualquer forma não importa o que passa pois na função vai mudar sempre pra true, qual o propósito disso?

Comment: PHP é executado antes de ir para o navegador, é executado no servidor, não tem sentido obter o valor da forma apontada, não vai executar o `if ($btn == true) {` porque o PHP já foi executado. São camadas diferentes.

Comment: O objetivo é sem sempre que o usuário clicar no button a variável php receber um valor para verificar e o button foi clicado

Comment: entendi Guilherme, sabe como posso fazer da forma mencionada acima? aqui no comentário

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8680/112052

Answer (score -2):

```js
 var numero = 0
function bscVarPhp(btn){
  /** Pode ser enviada um request via ajax para buscar a variavel*/
  /* Pode utilizar esta funccao para acessar as variaveis php*/
  /* var variavelPhp = <?php echo $variavel; ?> */
  /* Nesta mesma funcao pode ser alterado o valor do botao */
 
  btn.innerHTML = 'Clicou ' + numero
  /* pra teste coloquei uma variavel do js so pra demostrar o funcionamento */
  numero +=1  
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="bscVarPhp(this)" class="buscar_pje btn btn-warning"
 id="busca_pje" name="busca_pje"><i class='fas fa-sync-alt'></i> Buscar no PJe</button>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).